# How to create CandyMachine using umi?

Tags: metaplex, candy-machine, umi

I tried to follow the guide in Metaplex to create a CandyMachine using umi.

```js
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults'
import { publicKey, some, generateSigner, percentAmount, keypairIdentity, createSignerFromKeypair } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import {
  fetchCandyMachine,
  fetchCandyGuard,
  mplCandyMachine,
  create,
  setCandyMachineAuthority,
  setCandyGuardAuthority,
} from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine'

// Use the RPC endpoint of your choice.

import {
  createNft,
  TokenStandard,
} from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

async function manageCandyMachine() {
  const umi = createUmi('https://api.devnet.solana.com').use(mplCandyMachine())

  // Create the Collection NFT.
  const collectionUpdateAuthority = generateSigner(umi)
  const collectionMint = generateSigner(umi)

  const myKeypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(new Uint8Array([15,96,246,96,168,118,204,153,41,122,14,70,62,175,75,122,122,10,202,172,60,76,153,241,33,130,7,194,51,240,101,221,168,191,211,242,139,189,173,204,59,2,253,72,101,253,176,40,31,52,98,56,62,115,191,231,79,53,241,119,160,252,8,129]));
  const myKeypairSigner = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, myKeypair);
  umi.use(keypairIdentity(myKeypairSigner));

  await createNft(umi, {
    mint: collectionMint,
    authority: collectionUpdateAuthority,
    name: 'My Collection NFT',
    uri: 'https://example.com/path/to/some/json/metadata.json',
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(9.99, 2), // 9.99%
    isCollection: true,
  }).sendAndConfirm(umi)

  console.log(umi.identity.publicKey);

  // Create the Candy Machine.
  const candyMachine = generateSigner(umi);
  const creatorA = generateSigner(umi).publicKey;

  await(await create(umi, {
    candyMachine,
    collectionMint: collectionMint.publicKey,
    collectionUpdateAuthority,
    tokenStandard: TokenStandard.NonFungible,
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(9.99, 2), // 9.99%
    itemsAvailable: 5,
    creators: [
      {
        address: umi.identity.publicKey,
        verified: true,
        percentageShare: 100,
      },
    ],
    configLineSettings: some({
      prefixName: '',
      nameLength: 32,
      prefixUri: '',
      uriLength: 200,
      isSequential: false,
    }),
  })).sendAndConfirm(umi)


  const candyMachinePublicKey = candyMachine.publicKey
  console.log('pub key: ' + candyMachinePublicKey)
  
  // // Fetch the Candy Machine.
  const cm = await fetchCandyMachine(umi, candyMachinePublicKey)
  const candyGuard = await fetchCandyGuard(umi, cm.mintAuthority)

  console.log(cm.publicKey) // The public key of the Candy Machine account.
  console.log(cm.mintAuthority) // The mint authority of the Candy Machine which, in most cases, is the Candy Guard address.
  console.log(cm.data.itemsAvailable) // Total number of NFTs available.
  console.log(cm.itemsRedeemed) // Number of NFTs minted.
}

manageCandyMachine()
```

```
ts-node createCandyMachine.ts
```

Let me share the result below.

```
E:\Study\Try\mintcnft\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\umi-program-repository\src\createDefaultProgramRepository.ts:136
    return resolvedError ?? new ProgramErrorNotRecognizedError(program, error);
                            ^
ProgramErrorNotRecognizedError: The program [mplCandyMachineCore] at address [CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR] raised an error that is not recognized by the programs registered on the SDK. Please check the underlying program error below for more details.

Source: Program > mplCandyMachineCore [CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR]

Caused By: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0x39

Program Logs:
| Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
| Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
| Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR invoke [1]
| Program log: Instruction: InitializeV2
| Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [2]
| Program log: IX: Delegate
| Program log: Incorrect account owner
| Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 8136 of 777967 compute units
| Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x39
| Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR consumed 30019 of 799850 compute units
| Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR failed: custom program error: 0x39

    at Object.resolveError (E:\Study\Try\mintcnft\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\umi-program-repository\src\createDefaultProgramRepository.ts:136:29)
    at Object.sendTransaction (E:\Study\Try\mintcnft\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\umi-rpc-web3js\src\createWeb3JsRpc.ts:335:42)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async TransactionBuilder.sendAndConfirm (E:\Study\Try\mintcnft\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\umi\src\TransactionBuilder.ts:359:23)
    at async manageCandyMachine (E:\Study\Try\mintcnft\createCandyMachine.ts:46:3) {
  source: 'program',
  sourceDetails: 'mplCandyMachineCore [CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR]',
  cause: SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0x39
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (E:\Study\Try\mintcnft\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:5921:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (E:\Study\Try\mintcnft\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:5880:20)
      at async Object.sendTransaction (E:\Study\Try\mintcnft\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\umi-rpc-web3js\src\createWeb3JsRpc.ts:327:25)
      at async TransactionBuilder.sendAndConfirm (E:\Study\Try\mintcnft\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\umi\src\TransactionBuilder.ts:359:23)
      at async manageCandyMachine (E:\Study\Try\mintcnft\createCandyMachine.ts:46:3) {
    logs: [
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
      'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR invoke [1]',
      'Program log: Instruction: InitializeV2',
      'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [2]',
      'Program log: IX: Delegate',
      'Program log: Incorrect account owner',
      'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 8136 of 777967 compute units',
      'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x39',
      'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR consumed 30019 of 799850 compute units',
      'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR failed: custom program error: 0x39'
    ]
  },
  program: {
    name: 'mplCandyMachineCore',
    publicKey: 'CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR',
    getErrorFromCode: [Function: getErrorFromCode],
    getErrorFromName: [Function: getErrorFromName],
    isOnCluster: [Function: isOnCluster]
  },
  logs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeV2',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [2]',
    'Program log: IX: Delegate',
    'Program log: Incorrect account owner',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 8136 of 777967 compute units',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x39',
    'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR consumed 30019 of 799850 compute units',
    'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR failed: custom program error: 0x39'
  ]
}
```

I am not sure why this error occurs. And when I tried to get the candymachine account information with given candymachine id, I encountered wrong discriminator error.
Does someone have experience with resolving this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1):

The wallet that creates the candy machine has to be the update authority of the collection. This is required to delegate the permission to the candy machine to add more nfts to the collection.

This line is incorrect:

```
const collectionUpdateAuthority = generateSigner(umi)
```

Instead collectionUpdateAuthority should be myKeypairSigner.publicKey

I would recommend the same for creatorA. Otherwise royalties will go to a wallet that you might not be able to access if you don’t save that new creatorA keypair.

Personally I would always recommend to create a candy machine with sugar CLI. It is way easier and less error prone.

Comment: can you provide me a full correct code?